# GTKwave gives bad result?

Tags: system-verilog

I've tried to make an arithmetic shift to left.
What will happen if I use commend "i_a <<< i_b" and the i_b is negative (i_a and i_b are two's complement) ? It should give error or something like that instead it works somehow. For example if I had i_a = 1010 and i_b = 1000 then i_a should be shifter by -8 bits because of i_b being negative.

Here is the code :

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps 
`include "ashift_example1.sv"

module testbench;
    parameter BITY = 4;
    parameter OPER = 2;
    logic [OPER-1:0] i_oper;
    logic [OPER-1:0] i_rsn;
    logic signed [BITY-1:0] i_argA,i_argB;
    logic signed [BITY-1:0] o_result; 
    logic [1:0] o_status;

    ashift_example1  #(.BITS(BITY))   Shift_left    (.i_a(i_argA), .i_b(i_argB), .o_arith_left(o_result));

    initial
        begin
            $dumpfile("signals.vcd");  
                                            
            $dumpvars(0,testbench); 

            i_argA = '0;
            i_argB = '0;
            #1
            i_argA[3] = 1;
            i_argA[1] = 1;
            i_argB[0] = 1;
            #1
            i_argB[0] = 0;
            i_argB[1] = 1;
            #1
            i_argB[1] = 0;
            i_argB[3] = 1;
            #1

            $finish;
        end
endmodule
```

This is a testbench. And below is a module :

```
module ashift_example1(i_a, i_b, o_arith_left);
    parameter BITS = 4;
    input  logic signed [BITS-1:0] i_a, i_b;
    output logic signed [BITS-1:0] o_arith_left;
    // Blok opisujacy logike 
    always_comb
    begin
        // arytmetyczne przesuniecie o i_b bitow
        //                 w lewo (w strone MSB)
        o_arith_left = (i_a <<< i_b);      
    end
endmodule
```

I'm using SystemVerilog because this is what my school told me to use.
So What did I do wrong ? I've used "signed" for every input and output.

In gtkwave when i_b is negative it still works. I was told to use the if loop to get rid of negative i_b. But when I simulated with negative value it didn't give me an error.
So why should I give this if loop formula to get rid of negative numbers when they don't affect the program ?

If I had i_b = 1111 and i_a = 1010 then what should I have as a result ? GTKwave shows o_y = 0000
Even though the i_b = -1 (two's complement). So it should shift backwards ? or Should I give an error here ?

GTKwave should give not defined output but instead give 0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **11.4.10 Shift operators**

> ... The right
> operand is always treated as an unsigned number and has no effect on the signedness of the result. ...

So, your two-compliment is treated as a unsigned number, i.e., -1 (two-compliment 4'b1111) is treated as 15 and shifts the left operand by 15 positions in given direction.

Comment: so i_b is treated as an unsigned number even though it was at the beggining a sign number ?

Comment: It is treated as an unsigned number based on its bits representation as in the example. '-1' is treated as '15'.